# Initialize javascript array with objects result in array.length 0

Tags: javascript

This initializes an array of strings:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

This **should** initialize an array of objects I thought:

```
 var days = [moment(new Date(2014, 0, 1)), moment(new Date(2014, 0, 2))];
```

When I check days.length its 0 and not 2, WHY?

INFO: moment is momentJS a javascript date library.

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I do it that way:

```
var mom1 = moment(new Date(2014, 0, 1));
var mom2 = moment(new Date(2014, 0, 2));
var days = [mom1, mom2];
```

then days has a length of 2!

Thats weeiiiird!

**UPDATE 2**

```
// Arrange
var dateFactory = {
    getVisibleDateRange: function (startDate, endDate, visibleWeekDays) {
        // I do not care about the parameters, I just want to stub out the visible days with 2 stubs

        var days = [ moment(new Date(2014, 0, 1)), moment(new Date(2014, 0, 2))];
        return days;
    }
};

// load the service's module
beforeEach(module('clientApp', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('dateFactory', dateFactory);
}));
```

The dateFactory.getVisibleDateRange method is called from another angularjs factory.method1.

Inside this method1 the array momentjs objects are returned correctly with length 2 but inside the dateFactory the array has a length of 0.

OK I guess there won`t be a solution for that really specific problem. Prolly its my computer ;-)

Comment: You must have something else going on. I just ran the same thing and I got 2.

Comment: if you check days.length exactly after you created it like that. it's length will be 2 (by the standards)

Comment: @MikeCheel -- MomentJS is a JavaScript date library that makes working with dates SOOOOOOOOO much easier

Comment: @Pascal - Why are you doing `moment` and `new Date()`?

Comment: It looks like you're using `moment()` wrong

Comment: @Biotox really? Why? please correct me. Everything worked so far using momentJS. See documentation: You can create a Moment with a pre-existing native Javascript Date object.

var day = new Date(2011, 9, 16);
var dayWrapper = moment(day);

Comment: I think you need this: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/

Comment: You're using Moment fine. I mean, you could do like `moment([2014, 0, 1])` but either way / many other ways work. There's just something else going on.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qirivida/1/ i can't reproduce. Can you show your code at jsbin?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. Is this causing an error? (does the code this returns to have an empty array?) or does it just show up as empty in the debugger?

Comment: @VasilVanchuk Sorry I have no idea how to put the whole infrastructure of my project to jsbin.

Comment: Is it possible that it's just the debugger that reports a wrong number? What if you use `console.log( days.length )` instead?

Comment: @Pascal Hey, what editor do you use? Disclaimer: This is irrelevant to the question, but I like it s syntax highlighting...

Comment: @Abdullah0v0 Its WebStorm from jetbrains and Its my own edited syntax :P

Comment: @Pascal Thanks, looks like *really* good syntax highlighting!

Comment: @Juhana Console.log does not work in that IDE correctly: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/307680  I can not find any output/console window in that latest version...

Comment: Can't you test it in a browser?

Comment: @Juhana OK yes I checked in chrome the dev tools and console and saw the "2". So the problem seem to be the debugger of the WebStorm IDE ?

Comment: OK about WebStorm IDE and console output I was wrong: I have seen the "2" also in the window of the "Testrun" Tab.